# creating delete function in a shell script

Tags: shell

instead of deleting the record it duplicate and creates similar record, how can i fix this:

```
Delete()
{
            clear
            f=0
            echo "Enter Employee NO: \c"
            read no

            for j in `cat Employee.txt`
            do
                        eno=$(echo "$j" | cut -d "," -f 1)
                        enm=$(echo "$j" | cut -d "," -f 2)
                        eadd=$(echo "$j" | cut -d "," -f 3)
                        eage=$(echo "$j" | cut -d "," -f 4)
                        egen=$(echo "$j" | cut -d "," -f 5)
                        edes=$(echo "$j" | cut -d "," -f 6)
                        ebal=$(echo "$j" | cut -d "," -f 7)

                        if [ $no -eq $eno ]
                        then
                                    f=1                              
                                    line=$(echo "$eno,$enm,$eadd,$eage,$egen,$edes,$ebal,false")
                                    fnm=`cat Employee.txt`
                                    d=$(echo "$fnm" | sed s/$j/$line/g )
                                    echo $d > Employee.txt          
                                    echo "                 Delete Successfully                           "
                        fi
            done
            if [ f = 0 ]
            then
                          echo "               No Record Found              "
            fi
}
```

Comment: Show some sample lines from your file `Employee.txt` and tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i want to delete a record from the text file Attendance.txt with 7 column namely: Employee ID, Employee name, Employee Address, Employee age, Employee Gender, Employee Position, Employee salary and the output is:- 001,James,London,28,Male,Accountant,5000$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `awk` one-liner

```
echo "Enter Employee NO: \c"
read no

awk -F ',' -v eno=$no '{if ($1 == eno ){$8 = "false" }OFS=",";print }' \
Attendance.txt >tmp_file  && mv tmp_file Attendance.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much... that really helps